# How to prevent stoping the move when pressing more than one key(ActionScript)

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have 2 eventListeners:

1) key listener(A, S, D ,W); - for move object

2) key listener(WhiteSpace) - for jump object

so when i have pressed the A OR S OR D OR W keys then i press the whitespace to before this moment its all okey, the object is moving and jumping at the same time, but if i release the whitespace key while moving, the object stops...

so how can i make that when i release the key white space, the object will still moving?? don't paying attention to the other key releasing or pressing?

```
private function onKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {

    //trace(e.keyCode);
    switch(e.keyCode)
    {

    case 68:
    direction = 'left';
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveRight);
    break;
    case 65:
    direction = 'right';
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveLeft);
    break;
    case 32:
    jump() // the whitespace key
        break;

    }

private function moveRight(e:Event):void {

shape.x += 5;

}

private function moveLeft(e:Event):void {

shape.x += 5;

}

private function jump():void {

    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, jumpAnimation);
}

private function jumpAnimation(e:Event):void {

   //here code for jumping increasing the y and decreasing....
}

private function onKeyUp(e:Event):void {


    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveRight);
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveLeft);


}
```

Comment: Show us what you're working with, we can't debug your code if we don't have it. Also, just the relevant snippets please.

Comment: Can you a add your code? Guessing it's dificult without actually seeing it, but this seems a flag reset issue.

Comment: code added....., there is much other code, but i think this is the most relevant

Comment: so the problem is that the shape object is stoping when releasing some key, i can't understand why is happening that?, and how can this be fixed

Comment: its not only the whitespace, when i release any key, the other key cancels to , why is that??

Comment: You are removing the moveRight and moveLeft actions on any key up event, so it stops the right and left movement once any key is released no matter which key it is.  Usually for this kind of thing polling, like jeremynealbronw's answer is more reliable.  If you want to keep with you current structure, you would need to check which key is up and only remove the appropriate ENTER_FRAME listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a key up/down listeners and an enter frame listener and use some booleans to indicate what keys are down and update accordingly. Something like this might work:

```
var keyMap:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown );
addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp );
addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame );

function onKeyDown( event:KeyboardEvent ):void 
{
    keyMap[ event.keyCode ] = true;
}

function onKeyUp( event:KeyboardEvent ):void 
{
    keyMap[ event.keyCode ] = false;
}

function onEnterFrame( event:EnterFrame ):void 
{
    if( keyMap[ 68 ] ) 
    {
        // -- move left
    }

    if( keyMap[ 65 ] ) 
    {
        // -- move right 
    }

    // -- ect...
}
```

This would avoid a situation where one key up is causing all other keys from firing continuously because you would only be relying on a single key up or down from each key. The code to update your scene would be running continuously.

Comment: after i maked this, now i cannot press 2 keys at one time , just only one key, the others at the same time doesn't react :(, and also if i am pressing the right and then pressing the left, it will go the left ignoring the right key, but when i press the right key and then pressing the left its still moving on the right ignoring the left key o_O, xmmm

Comment: and also what is better to use the switch or the if statements???, because if i will need to set 2 elements keyMap[jump] and keyMap[left or right] the switch case will execut only 1? so the if statement if better

Comment: Neither is better really. It is a matter of preference and convenience.

Comment: well i have used the IF statement and its worked all GOOD))) thanks for the help))) :)